# Classroom API Access for Project Co-Owners

Tags: google-classroom

Context: I've been granted Classroom API and see it on my console

[image: Classroom API access enabled]

Problem: I added another owner to my project but he doesn't see Classroom API listed in Enabled API's and Classroom API does not show up in search like it does for me.

Questions: Has anyone else experienced this? Is there something I need to do to enable for co-owners?

Comment: I believe this is as expected. They won't be able to see the entry, but API requests should still succeed.

Comment: The developer preview for the Classroom API is now over and it is open to all developers: http://googleforeducation.blogspot.com/2015/08/general-availability-for-classroom-api.html